# Binding and validating null fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to pass ProductVM from view to controller, but ProductVM contains some fields that remain null when passed. Because of this in the controller, when I try to validate ModelState.IsValid it becomes false, so the code execution doesn't go any further. I need a way around this situation, but I don't see how it can be done nicely(

**Model ProductVM**

```
public class ProductVM
    {
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategorySelectList { get; set; }
    }
```

**Model Product:**

```
public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
        public double Price { get; set; }

        public string Image { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Category Type")]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult Upsert( ProductVM productVM)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {...}
        }
```

**View:**

```
@model JamFox.Models.ViewModels.ProductVM
@{
    var title = "Create product";
}
<form method="post" asp-action="Upsert" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @if (Model.Product.Id != 0)
    {
        title = "Edit product";
        <input asp-for="Product.Id" hidden />
    }
    <div class="form-group row">
        <h2 class="text-dark pl-3">
            @title
        </h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4 my-1">
                        <label asp-for="Product.Name"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8 my-1">
                        <input asp-for="Product.Name" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Product.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4 my-1">
                        <label asp-for="Product.Price"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8 my-1">
                        <input asp-for="Product.Price" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Product.Price" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4 my-1">
                        <label asp-for="Product.CategoryId"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8 my-1">
                        <select asp-for="Product.CategoryId" asp-items="@Model.CategorySelectList" class="form-control">
                            <option selected>--Select category--</option>
                        </select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Product.CategoryId" class="text-danger"></span>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4 my-1">
                        <label asp-for="Product.Description"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8 my-1">
                        <textarea asp-for="Product.Description" class="form-control summernote"></textarea>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Product.Description" class="text-danger"></span>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4 my-1">
                        Image
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8 my-1">
                        <input asp-for="Product.Image" type="file" name="files" id="uploadBox" multiple class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="form-group row offset-4 ">
                    <div class="col-6 pt-2">
                        @if (Model.Product.Id != 0)
                        {
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark w-100 pt-1">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-floppy-disk" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
                                Save
                            </button>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <button type="submit" onclick="return validateInput()" class="btn btn-dark w-100 pt-1">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-floppy-disk" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
                                Save
                            </button>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 pt-2">
                        <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-dark w-100 pt-1">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
                            Back
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 offset-1">
                @if (Model.Product.Id != 0)
                {
                    <img src="@WC.ImagePath@Model.Product.Image" class="border-3" />
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
@section Scripts{
    @{
        <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    }
    <script>
        function validateInput() {
            if (document.getElementById("uploadBox").value == "") {
                Swal.fire(
                    'Error!',
                    'Please upload an image!',
                    'error'
                )
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.summernote').summernote({
                height: 250
            });
        }); S
    </script>
}
```

I tried specifying a Bind in the controller to check only the required fields, but it didn't help